# how to speed up hibernate criteria 'ilike queries' with oracle database

Tags: performance, oracle, hibernate

We are using hibernate with oracle (11) and have severe performance problems due to the usage of 'ilike', the case insensitive 'like'.

The java / hibernate code looks like:

```
 c1.add( Restrictions.ilike("address", address) );
```

which results in a sql statement like

```
 select * from ACCOUNT where lower(ADDRESS_1) = ?
```

The 'lower' function makes it impossible for oracle to use an index which results in a full table scan.

I was thinking about introducing a new column to the db table that contains the lower case content of address.
I could then use :

```
c1.add( Restrictions.ilike("addressLCase", address.toLowerCase()) );
```

... but I really don't like the idea to store the content twice...

Then I thought of creating an index with lower case

```
CREATE INDEX ADDRESS_1_IDX ON ACCOUNT  lower(  ADDRESS_1   )  ;
```

but this didn't work, since I cannot convince the optimizer to use this index...

So what can I do to create a fast query with hibernate criteria API and 'ilike' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function based index would be my choice. Just remember:

- Use the Cost Based Optimizer. Function based indexes are only visible to the Cost Based Optimizer and will not be used by the Rule Based Optimizer ever.

Excerpt from [this](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_function_based_index_2.html) article.